# How do I Change default database in cakephp controller in cake 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Currently I have a plugin that is calling

`$this->loadModel('PluginName.TableName');`

Per documentation 
[installing plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html)

at the route level 
sitename.com/plugin-name/

The Proper database source is getting called

However 
sitename.com/plugin-name/actionname

is calling the default source

I have

`public static function defaultConnectionName()
    {
        return 'localsource';
    }`

Set in the table model

what  I need is to call something like

`$this->ModelName->setDataSource('localsource');`

this was the way it was done in cake 2.x but that has been removed in cake 3.x

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use other than default database which will get by naming convention. Then there are two way ::

```
$this->loadModel('TableName');
```

or

Write this on the top of controller use `Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;`

then

```
$TableName = TableRegistry::get('TableName');
```